# Jetpack compose testing : how to getcurrent activity after starting new activity from testrule

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-testing, android-jetpack-compose-testing

How to get current activity ( newly started activity ) , started from ui testing. Is there anyway to get its instance using composeTestRule

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would write seperate test methods / a separate test class that verifies the behaviour of the newly started Activity in isolation. So I don't think there is a way to actually access properties or the context of a newly started Activity.

If you only want to check whether a new Activity was successfully started after a button press, try out the following code:

```
@Test
fun testStartActivity() {
    Intents.init()
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        MyAppTheme {
            MainScreen()
        }
    }
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("start Activity").performClick()
    intended(hasComponent(MySecondActivity::class.java.name))
    Intents.release()
}
```

Check out [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/intent/Intents#intended(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Candroid.content.Intent%3E,androidx.test.espresso.intent.VerificationMode)) for the `intended` function.
If you want to test whether intent extras are passed properly, have a look at [this question](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/intent/Intents#intended(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Candroid.content.Intent%3E,androidx.test.espresso.intent.VerificationMode)).

Comment: composeTestRule.activity gives the activity where the test was launched,I need to access the current activity of the app ( an activity which was created while testing) say after a button click, an activity was launched. @BenjyTec

Comment: @VIGNESH I see. I updated my answer, let me know if it works, I can't test it out myself right now.

Comment: Hi @BenjyTec,Thanks for the response. But I want to get the currentActivity Instance which was launched.I got the same via 
ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(
                            Stage.RESUMED)